# How to use VSCode's formatter from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Someone in my team uses vim, but the rest of us use VSCode's default formatter (i.e. `vscode.typescript-language-features`). I'd like to add a git precommit hook or something that invokes the formatter without opening up the app.

See also:

- [Possible to invoke a VSCode extension command from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409369/possible-to-invoke-a-vscode-extension-command-from-command-line)

Comment: I think you would have to extract the code from vscode source and make it an executable yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of July 2021, it seems vscode does not provide any way to run its formatter outside of the app itself

Answer (score 3):

VS Code doesn't have "*a* formatter". It has multiple builtin formatting providers and [extensions can implement their own formatting providers as well](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentFormattingEditProvider).

There's no easy way to do what is being asked for as far as I am aware at the time of this writing.

I'd suggest to figure out if there's an underlying formatting tool that whichever formatter you're using in VS Code is built on top of / wrapping, and then find out if you can invoke that took from the commandline. This will probably require reading some docs and/or source code. I give an example of the process for doing this in my answer to [What JSON formatter does Visual Studio Code use to format JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76056894/11107541). It's a bit involved and the *exact* process very likely varies significantly depending on the formatter / VS Code extension providing the formatting capability, so this is kind of the best answer I can imagine giving without giving a thorough answer for every formatter under the sun for all time here, which [would be too broad](/help/dont-ask).

But to try to generalize,

- Find out which extension is providing the formatting functionality- it may be one you manually installed, or [one that is built in to VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions). The formatter should be indicated in the status bar- click the `{}` icon to get a popup with that info. Or check if you've touched the `editor.defaultFormatter` setting for any [language override settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)
- Go to that extension's page in the Extensions View in VS Code
- If the docs mention that there's an underlying formatter tool, then you can skip a lot of the below steps
- Find the link to the extension's source code repository (it will only be there if the extension provides that link in its [extension manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest)
- If the extension is closed-source, you'll have to work with the extension as it is installed (see the `.vscode/extensions/` directory under your user home directory)
- From this point, you'll have to figure out how the formatting is implemented and hope that it's implemented by calling an underlying formatting tool that you can use via commandline or write a commandline wrapper for. You can try looking to see if the `depndencies` property of the extension manifest (package.json file) gives any info, or otherwise grep for things related to [`DocumentFormattingEditProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentFormattingEditProvider) and see if there are any calls to a non-JS program.

This could theoretically be simpler if VS Code made it so, but it does not- at least- not at the time of this writing. See [Possible to invoke a VSCode extension command from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54409369/11107541) and [Can a command be send to VSCode, directly from the integrated terminal (integrated terminal -> VSCode API)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68460556/11107541), for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great git hooks tool called [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) and its documentation can be found [here](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/).

Here is an example of it inside of a `package.json` file that uses [pretty-quick](https://github.com/azz/pretty-quick#readme) to execute [prettier](https://prettier.io/) whenever a **git** `pre-commit` is executed.

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  },
....
```

I find this method far superior to running prettier on every file save.

Comment: Do you know how to set it up with vscode's default formatter instead of prettier?

Comment: I do not, however I would recommend using prettier because you can configure each project with different rules. While I assume that VS-Code's default formatter uses a global format for projects of the same type.

Answer (score -2):

Format Document (Ctrl+Shift+I) - Format the entire active file. Format Selection (Ctrl+K Ctrl+F) - Format the selected text.

Comment: How does this work *from the command line*?